# HTTP REST Response in CQRS

Tags: rest, cqrs, http-put

I am building HTTP REST API and implementing CQRS, DDD, ES, and microservices concept for the API.

For example, I want to build API for ordering system. The order contains order status, customer data, employee data, cart items, shipping data. The order command service and order query service are using different code, different databases. and different ip / port.

Customer data consists of customer id, first name, last name, contact numbers, etc. Employee data like sales and staff consists of employee id, email, name, and role. Shipping data consists of shipping address, city, zipcode, shipping note, shipping method, and shipping cost. Cart items contains product id and qty. Customer data, product data, employee data, and shipping method data are produced from other services.

I have two questions when I want to developing it.

1. When I build the POST method to create new order from sales / staff, what should be in a **request** payload? Is it possible to only send customer id and the employee id as request payload? Or should I send the customer name and contact numbers as payload?
2. When I build the POST / PUT method, should I return response code 200? What should be in the **response**? For example, I only send the customer id and employee id when a staff create new order to the order command service. Should the response body shows the full order data that contains other services result (like name and contact numbers from customer id, and so on)? Not only that, the denormalizer system is rather slow. The denormalizer is needed to get the customer and employee detail. It depends on network latency and other services responses. But, user want to get the order data instantly.

What should I do to develop HTTP REST API in a correct way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am building HTTP REST API and implementing CQRS, DDD, ES, and microservices concept for the API.

Cool.  Keep firmly in your mind that the REST API part is part of your integration component; its purpose is to ensure that old clients can continue to take advantage of your services, even as the implementation of those services evolves.

Jim Webber, [Domain-Driven Design for RESTful Systems](https://yow.eventer.com/events/1004/talks/1047)

> The web is not your domain, it's a document management system.  All the HTTP verbs apply to the document management domain. URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation.  Work (ex: issuing commands to the domain model) is a side effect of managing resources.  In other words, the resources are part of the anti-corruption layer.  You should expect to have many many more resources in your integration domain than you do business objects in your business domain.

---

> When I build the POST method to create new order from sales / staff, what should be in a request payload?

Note the point above about "many more resources" -- you can provide as many different ways (protocols) to create a new order as you are willing to support.

From the point of view of microservices, placing an order probably touches on a number of different business capabilities.  See Udi Dahan's writings on [UI Composition Techniques](http://udidahan.com/2012/06/23/ui-composition-techniques-for-correct-service-boundaries/), the same concerns have play in machine to machine interfaces.

So from the point of view of the web endpoint that ends up communicating the order with the service(s), the information that you need is going to depend on what the exposed endpoints need.

From the point of view of the client: part of the point of providing a REST API is that the integration resources can guide the client to construct the final submission.  Think online shopping experience - Amazon doesn't ask you to type in a bunch of SKUs, or customer ids.  You just submit a sequence of forms until you get to a screen that lets you make one last check of the data, and then you submit it if it looks right.

So one of the screens along the way could be something that helps the client figure out what the employee id should be (here's a search form, here's a list to choose from, etc).

> When I build the POST / PUT method, should I return response code 200?

Generally speaking, 200 is fine.  Unless you are anticipating clients that react cleverly to different forms of success, that will cover most of your cases.

[202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3) is a finer grained status that's often used when processing is not going to be completed immediately.  "Hi, we got your order.  Here's a link you can use to check on progress."

For instance, if you were using an architecture where the REST api was going to simply write the order request into a queue for the microservice consumers to pick up, then 202 is conceptually accurate "we wrote it down, and the services will decide for themselves what to do about it".

> user want to get the order data instantly.

*Instantly* isn't a latency that you are ever likely to meet, so you'll want an SLA that's a bit more forgiving.

I wouldn't expect that kind of a problem; after all, if your design is CQRS, you can have a denormalized representation of a lot of the data available in a hot cache.  If that representation is independently addressable, and cacheable, you may be able to re-use a copy that's stored on the client.

> But, how the backend API know that user wants to buy that product to an order? We receive the SKU as payload, don't we?

Not necessarily -- we receive something the REST API can use to calculate the SKU.  It could be something else.  But a SKU is fine: the main point from the perspective of the client is that the message formats didn't change; the main point from the perspective of the *shopper* is that she didn't have to care what was in the payload, because she had stable semantic cues to work from (ie: she was looking at the product name, but what the form submitted under the covers was the SKU).

> What is the ideal way to map the HTTP verbs, URI, and domain objects?

Other way around: what's the right way to make your backend service look like a web site?

Ever use your web browser to configure a wireless router?  How does that work -- a routers internals are nothing like a web site.  There's no reason that the app that you use to ask questions on stack overflow should work as a router configuration tool.  Yet it does, because the API on the router knows how to duck like a web site while at the same time sending the right instructions to the back end.

The REST client is only looking at the messages it receives; it doesn't know *anything* about domain objects; it only knows about representations of resources (think documents describing things).

The ideal way to map the HTTP verbs, and so on, it to pretend to be a dumb document store.

Comment: `Think online shopping experience - Amazon doesn't ask you to type in a bunch of SKUs, or customer ids. You just submit a sequence of forms` That's right. But, how the backend API know that user wants to buy that product to an order? We receive the SKU as payload, don't we? I think if we send the product data from client (product name, price, etc), it would be vulnerable and uncontrolled. it becomes no validation. 

`you may be able to re-use a copy that's stored on the client.` How to get the data stored in the client from backend side? Is it the task that should be done from frontend side?

Comment: `All the HTTP verbs apply to the document management domain. URIs do NOT map onto domain objects.` Sorry, I didn't catch that. Does it mean that HTTP verbs and URI should be adjusted to the web page (front-end)? Should I develop HTTP API as layer / controller to manage the payload and send certain part of the payload to the right service? What is the ideal way to map the HTTP verbs, URI, and domain objects? Could you help me to give some examples about this? Thank you.

Comment: For the creation of new resource, should HTTP 201 Created be returned instead of the more generic HTTP 200?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a late response, yet it might be helpful for someone who is looking how to implement CQRS architectural pattern via HTTP.
During my discovery process, I decided to share my findings and ended up writing a series of articles on how to do CQRS via HTTP.

1. [CQRS: Intro](https://valerii-udodov.com/2020/01/13/cqrs-intro/)
2. [CQRS: Commanding via HTTP](https://valerii-udodov.com/2020/02/20/cqrs-commanding-via-http/)
3. [CQRS: Querying via HTTP](https://valerii-udodov.com/2020/03/10/cqrs-querying-via-http/)

I particularly want to point out **that RESTful architecture is conceptually different from CQRS**, thus not a good fit for a purpose. I've tried to give an exhaustive comparison of two architectures in the Commanding via HTTP article.

Apart from the theoretical aspect, during the writing process, I managed to build two ready-to-use, independent middleware that are built to help you adopt CQRS in your ASP NET Core project. [HTTP Commanding](https://github.com/vudodov/http-commanding) and [HTTP Querying](https://github.com/vudodov/http-querying).

Hope it helps, if you have any questions, don't hesitate and shoot me a message.